# How to deeplink to a UIViewController accessed from a UIViewController in a UINavigationController in a UITabBarViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, deep-linking

I need to deeplink to a UIViewController that can be accessed from another UIViewController that resides in a UINavigationViewController which itself is a tab in a UITableViewController.

Basically it looks like this

UITabBarViewController -> (Each Tab) UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> (Press UIBarButtonItem) -> TheViewControllerIWant

Due to the constraints of the project I'm working on, this has all been created programmatically in my AppDelegate. I cannot use Storyboards to solve this problem.

Here is my existing code. It gets me to the ViewController, but does not give me a way to navigate back to the ViewController in the tab

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication * ) application openURL: (NSURL *) url sourceApplication: (NSString *) sourceApplication annotation: (id) annotation {

    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString: @"myApp"]) {

        if ([url.host isEqualToString: @"account"])
        {
            self.window.rootViewController = [[EditAccountViewController alloc] init];
        }
}
```

I have also tried this as a start, but have no way to navigate forward to the next ViewController from the one in the TabBar to it:

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication * ) application openURL: (NSURL *) url sourceApplication: (NSString *) sourceApplication annotation: (id) annotation {

    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString: @"myApp"]) {

        if ([url.host isEqualToString: @"account"])
        {
            [_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
            self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you need to manually trigger all actions then....

So you'll need to first select the first tab on your TabBarController
Then you'll need to get the UIViewController of the first Tab and push the destination ViewController in the Navigation Controller...

```
[_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
UIViewController *myVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers.firstObject;
UIViewController *destinationVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"vc.nib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[myVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: If it were the 2nd 3rd etc object in a tabbar, would there be a corresponding .secondObject .thirdObject etc to call for vcs?

Comment: If I needed to go one level deeper and push another VC after the one for the above answer, how would I do that?

Comment: if you want to keep the navigation stack in a particular order, you'll have to push a new viewController on the stack after the next push. If you don't care about the stack, then you can init the final destnation View Controller and push it as the first VC in the Navigation Stack. As for your other question, `self.tabBarController.viewControllers` is an `NSArray` so you would reference other ViewControllers like `[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];' , 3 , 4, etc....